# Designing a Performant Materialized View for Web Analytics Data in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have the following schema in Clickhouse for a web analytics system with tens of millions of records:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS analytics.Records
(
  -- performance
  PerfIsProcessed UInt8, --bool
  PerfPageLoadTime UInt16,
  PerfDomainLookupTime UInt16,
  PerfTCPConnectTime UInt16,
  PerfServerResponseTime UInt16,
  PerfPageDownloadTime UInt16,
  PerfRedirectTime UInt16,
  PerfDOMInteractiveTime UInt16,
  PerfContentLoadTime UInt16,
  PerfResource UInt16,
  
  -- geo:asn
  GeoIPAutonomousSystemNumber UInt16,
  GeoIPAutonomousSystemOrganization String,
  
  -- requirements
  PublicInstanceID String,
  Mode UInt8,
  Created Datetime
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/analytics/Records', '{replica}')
ORDER BY (Created, Mode, xxHash32(PublicInstanceID))
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(Created)
SAMPLE BY (xxHash32(PublicInstanceID));
```

Now, I want to create a materialized view to obtain the following data:

```sql
SELECT
    toStartOfDay(Created) AS Date,
    AVG(PerfPageLoadTime) AS AvgPageLoadTime,
    MIN(PerfPageLoadTime) AS MinPageLoadTime,
    MAX(PerfPageLoadTime) AS MaxPageLoadTime,
    MEDIAN(PerfPageLoadTime) AS MedianPageLoadTime,
    STDDEV(PerfPageLoadTime) AS PageLoadTimeStdDev,
    AVG(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS AvgDomainLookupTime,
    MIN(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS MinDomainLookupTime,
    MAX(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS MaxDomainLookupTime,
    MEDIAN(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS MedianDomainLookupTime,
    STDDEV(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS DomainLookupTimeStdDev,
    AVG(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS AvgTCPConnectTime,
    MIN(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS MinTCPConnectTime,
    MAX(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS MaxTCPConnectTime,
    MEDIAN(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS MedianTCPConnectTime,
    STDDEV(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS TCPConnectTimeStdDev,
    AVG(PerfServerResponseTime) AS AvgServerResponseTime,
    MIN(PerfServerResponseTime) AS MinServerResponseTime,
    MAX(PerfServerResponseTime) AS MaxServerResponseTime,
    MEDIAN(PerfServerResponseTime) AS MedianServerResponseTime,
    STDDEV(PerfServerResponseTime) AS ServerResponseTimeStdDev,
    GeoIPAutonomousSystemOrganization
FROM
    analytics.Records
GROUP BY
    Date, GeoIPAutonomousSystemOrganization;
```

I would like to design the materialized view in a performant way considering the following requirements:

- The accuracy of the data is not critical; a 5% error is acceptable.
- I only need data from the previous day and the days before that; live data is not necessary.
- Performance is crucial, and I don't want the gathering and calculation of this data to impact the performance of the original table.

Any suggestions on how to design the materialized view to meet these requirements would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Records
(
  -- performance
  PerfIsProcessed UInt8, --bool
  PerfPageLoadTime UInt16,
  PerfDomainLookupTime UInt16,
  PerfTCPConnectTime UInt16,
  PerfServerResponseTime UInt16,
  PerfPageDownloadTime UInt16,
  PerfRedirectTime UInt16,
  PerfDOMInteractiveTime UInt16,
  PerfContentLoadTime UInt16,
  PerfResource UInt16,
  GeoIPAutonomousSystemNumber UInt16,
  GeoIPAutonomousSystemOrganization String,
  PublicInstanceID String,
  Mode UInt8,
  Created Datetime
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (Created, Mode, xxHash32(PublicInstanceID))
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(Created);
```

```sql
create table agg (
    Date                               DateTime,
    AvgPageLoadTime                    AggregateFunction(avg, UInt16),
    MinPageLoadTime                    SimpleAggregateFunction(min,UInt16),
    MaxPageLoadTime                    SimpleAggregateFunction(max,UInt16),
    MedianPageLoadTime                 AggregateFunction(quantilesTDigest(0.5), UInt16),
    PageLoadTimeStdDev                 AggregateFunction(stddevSamp, UInt16),
    AvgDomainLookupTime                AggregateFunction(avg, UInt16),
    MinDomainLookupTime                SimpleAggregateFunction(min,UInt16),
    MaxDomainLookupTime                SimpleAggregateFunction(max,UInt16),
    MedianDomainLookupTime             AggregateFunction(quantilesTDigest(0.5), UInt16),
    DomainLookupTimeStdDev             AggregateFunction(stddevSamp, UInt16),
    AvgTCPConnectTime                  AggregateFunction(avg, UInt16),
    MinTCPConnectTime                  SimpleAggregateFunction(min,UInt16),
    MaxTCPConnectTime                  SimpleAggregateFunction(max,UInt16),
    MedianTCPConnectTime               AggregateFunction(quantilesTDigest(0.5), UInt16),
    TCPConnectTimeStdDev               AggregateFunction(stddevSamp, UInt16),
    AvgServerResponseTime              AggregateFunction(avg, UInt16),
    MinServerResponseTime              SimpleAggregateFunction(min,UInt16),
    MaxServerResponseTime              SimpleAggregateFunction(max,UInt16),
    MedianServerResponseTime           AggregateFunction(quantilesTDigest(0.5), UInt16),
    ServerResponseTimeStdDev           AggregateFunction(stddevSamp, UInt16),
    GeoIPAutonomousSystemOrganization  String
) Engine = AggregatingMergeTree order by (GeoIPAutonomousSystemOrganization, Date)
partition by toYYYYMM(Date);
```

```sql
CREATE materialized view agg_mv to agg as 
SELECT
    toStartOfDay(Created) AS Date,
    avgState(PerfPageLoadTime) AS AvgPageLoadTime,
    min(PerfPageLoadTime) AS MinPageLoadTime,
    max(PerfPageLoadTime) AS MaxPageLoadTime,
    quantilesTDigestState(0.5)(PerfPageLoadTime) AS MedianPageLoadTime,
    stddevSampState(PerfPageLoadTime) AS PageLoadTimeStdDev,
    avgState(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS AvgDomainLookupTime,
    min(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS MinDomainLookupTime,
    max(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS MaxDomainLookupTime,
    quantilesTDigestState(0.5)(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS MedianDomainLookupTime,
    stddevSampState(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS DomainLookupTimeStdDev,
    avgState(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS AvgTCPConnectTime,
    min(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS MinTCPConnectTime,
    max(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS MaxTCPConnectTime,
    quantilesTDigestState(0.5)(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS MedianTCPConnectTime,
    stddevSampState(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS TCPConnectTimeStdDev,
    avgState(PerfServerResponseTime) AS AvgServerResponseTime,
    min(PerfServerResponseTime) AS MinServerResponseTime,
    max(PerfServerResponseTime) AS MaxServerResponseTime,
    quantilesTDigestState(0.5)(PerfServerResponseTime) AS MedianServerResponseTime,
    stddevSampState(PerfServerResponseTime) AS ServerResponseTimeStdDev,
    GeoIPAutonomousSystemOrganization
FROM
    Records
GROUP BY
    Date, GeoIPAutonomousSystemOrganization;
```

```sql
set max_partitions_per_insert_block=0;

insert into Records 
SELECT * FROM generateRandom('PerfIsProcessed UInt8, PerfPageLoadTime UInt16, PerfDomainLookupTime UInt16, PerfTCPConnectTime UInt16, PerfServerResponseTime UInt16, PerfPageDownloadTime UInt16, PerfRedirectTime UInt16, PerfDOMInteractiveTime UInt16, PerfContentLoadTime UInt16, PerfResource UInt16, GeoIPAutonomousSystemNumber UInt16, GeoIPAutonomousSystemOrganization String, PublicInstanceID String, Mode UInt8,Created Datetime', 1, 10, 2) LIMIT 100000;
```

```sql
SELECT
    AVG(PerfPageLoadTime) AS AvgPageLoadTime,
    MIN(PerfPageLoadTime) AS MinPageLoadTime,
    MAX(PerfPageLoadTime) AS MaxPageLoadTime,
    median(PerfPageLoadTime) AS MedianPageLoadTime,
    stddevSamp(PerfPageLoadTime) AS PageLoadTimeStdDev,
    AVG(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS AvgDomainLookupTime,
    MIN(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS MinDomainLookupTime,
    MAX(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS MaxDomainLookupTime,
    median(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS MedianDomainLookupTime,
    stddevSamp(PerfDomainLookupTime) AS DomainLookupTimeStdDev,
    AVG(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS AvgTCPConnectTime,
    MIN(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS MinTCPConnectTime,
    MAX(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS MaxTCPConnectTime,
    median(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS MedianTCPConnectTime,
    stddevSamp(PerfTCPConnectTime) AS TCPConnectTimeStdDev,
    AVG(PerfServerResponseTime) AS AvgServerResponseTime,
    MIN(PerfServerResponseTime) AS MinServerResponseTime,
    MAX(PerfServerResponseTime) AS MaxServerResponseTime,
    median(PerfServerResponseTime) AS MedianServerResponseTime,
    stddevSamp(PerfServerResponseTime) AS ServerResponseTimeStdDev
FROM Records \G

──────
AvgPageLoadTime:          32742.03003
MinPageLoadTime:          0
MaxPageLoadTime:          65533
MedianPageLoadTime:       32391.5
PageLoadTimeStdDev:       18896.77446066387
AvgDomainLookupTime:      32769.65665
MinDomainLookupTime:      0
MaxDomainLookupTime:      65535
MedianDomainLookupTime:   33132.5
DomainLookupTimeStdDev:   18901.354485375236
AvgTCPConnectTime:        32767.53588
MinTCPConnectTime:        0
MaxTCPConnectTime:        65534
MedianTCPConnectTime:     32979.5
TCPConnectTimeStdDev:     18934.111527912424
AvgServerResponseTime:    32806.32915
MinServerResponseTime:    0
MaxServerResponseTime:    65535
MedianServerResponseTime: 33434
ServerResponseTimeStdDev: 18907.003897612496
```

```sql
SELECT
    avgMerge(AvgPageLoadTime) AS AvgPageLoadTime,
    min(MinPageLoadTime) AS MinPageLoadTime,
    max(MaxPageLoadTime) AS MaxPageLoadTime,
    quantilesTDigestMerge(0.5)(MedianPageLoadTime) AS MedianPageLoadTime,
    stddevSampMerge(PageLoadTimeStdDev) AS PageLoadTimeStdDev,
    avgMerge(AvgDomainLookupTime) AS AvgDomainLookupTime,
    min(MinDomainLookupTime) AS MinDomainLookupTime,
    max(MaxDomainLookupTime) AS MaxDomainLookupTime,
    quantilesTDigestMerge(0.5)(MedianDomainLookupTime) AS MedianDomainLookupTime,
    stddevSampMerge(DomainLookupTimeStdDev) AS DomainLookupTimeStdDev,
    avgMerge(AvgTCPConnectTime) AS AvgTCPConnectTime,
    min(MinTCPConnectTime) AS MinTCPConnectTime,
    max(MaxTCPConnectTime) AS MaxTCPConnectTime,
    quantilesTDigestMerge(0.5)(MedianTCPConnectTime) AS MedianTCPConnectTime,
    stddevSampMerge(TCPConnectTimeStdDev) AS TCPConnectTimeStdDev,
    avgMerge(AvgServerResponseTime) AS AvgServerResponseTime,
    min(MinServerResponseTime) AS MinServerResponseTime,
    max(MaxServerResponseTime) AS MaxServerResponseTime,
    quantilesTDigestMerge(0.5)(MedianServerResponseTime) AS MedianServerResponseTime,
    stddevSampMerge(ServerResponseTimeStdDev) AS ServerResponseTimeStdDev
FROM agg \G

AvgPageLoadTime:          32742.03003
MinPageLoadTime:          0
MaxPageLoadTime:          65533
MedianPageLoadTime:       [32712.125]
PageLoadTimeStdDev:       18896.77446066387
AvgDomainLookupTime:      32769.65665
MinDomainLookupTime:      0
MaxDomainLookupTime:      65535
MedianDomainLookupTime:   [32751.398]
DomainLookupTimeStdDev:   18901.354485375236
AvgTCPConnectTime:        32767.53588
MinTCPConnectTime:        0
MaxTCPConnectTime:        65534
MedianTCPConnectTime:     [32821.75]
TCPConnectTimeStdDev:     18934.111527912424
AvgServerResponseTime:    32806.32915
MinServerResponseTime:    0
MaxServerResponseTime:    65535
MedianServerResponseTime: [32799.582]
ServerResponseTimeStdDev: 18907.003897612496
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now do you think this mv has impact on original table insert performance? Is good idea to write a script to query from original table and insert into target table once a day, or is it better to use MV in the sense of performance?

Comment: it will reduce insert performance on 20%. From my perspective MV is better because in my system it's impossible to aggregate data once a day.

Comment: Why it is impossible? Can't understand.

Comment: Because 1. I need data in MV in realtime. 2. I have so much data that it's impossible to aggregate one day data at once.